# Troubleshooting slow connections in large data centers

Tags: troubleshooting

I’ve been asked this question - or a variation of it - during some recente job interviews. I think my answers were adequate (involving reducing scope, packet tracer with many probes, etc) but I’m curious too know kind of answers others would give.

Here’s the question: Two servers, located at opposite ends of a large datacenter (think L3 Clos type of topology) are reporting abnormal latency between them. How would you go about troubleshooting such cases?

Comment: Welcome to Network Engineering!  Questions like these generate lots of opinions which are, sadly, off-topic here.  We strive for objective answers to questions.  If (when) you have enough reputation for chat, you're welcome to ask it there.